# continuous function in a triangle

Tags: continuity, triangles, functional-equations

Let $S$ be an equilateral triangle, and $f$ is a continuous function such that for any point $O$ inside $S$, with distances $x,y,z$ from vertices of $S$,
$f(x)+f(y)+f(z)=0$.
Prove that $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: Where $f$ is defined?? What have you tried?

Comment: $f$ is defined on set of all points inside $S$ to $\Bbb R$

Comment: I'm not certain this is true. What if some $f(\cdot)$ are negative?

Comment: $f(0)$ is not defined, because $O$ is inside triangle. @Erik M

Comment: This has been asked several times on AOPS, without any answers. See [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1514613p9011692), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1364813p7493253), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1305175p6972217), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h69707p407844), [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1435346p8127357) and [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h363767p1997460).

Comment: @M.SH $f$ is not defined on the " set of all points inside $S$". It is defined on the set of all possible distances of a point $O$ inside $S$ to vertices of $S$. If you take "inside $S$" in the nonstrict sense (i.e. $O$ can be on the sides and even vertices), that set is the closed interval $[0,a]$ (where $a$ is the length of the sides of $S$), and if you take that phrase in the strict sense (i.e. $O$ must be a point of the interior region), that set is the open interval $(0,a)$.

Comment: @M.SH You have to clear things up, not only by specifying the meaning of the phrase "inside $S$", but also by specifying what values the function $f$ can take. For an $x$ in the domain of $f$, is $f(x)$ considered to be a rational/real/complex number? A matrix with entries from the field of $13$-adic numbes? Or what? I suggest editing the post, and specifying these simply using a sentence "Let $f:D\to C$ ...", where $D$ is the domain and $C$ is the codomain you intended to use.

Comment: The link given in one of the solutions in the link above (i.e. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18634/229831)) contains a solution showing that when you state the problem by considering points inside the triangle in the strict sense, only the constant zero function work, even if you drop the assumption of continuity of $ f $.